# Show layout when soft keyboard opens

Tags: android, android-layout

There is a `CardView` with an `EditText` and when the keyboard opens, it is placed right below the `EditText`. But as shown below, the keyboard is too close to the EditText and it is hard to press the  "send" button because there is not enough space.

EditText:
[image]

EditText with focus:
[image]

Is there any way to show the keyboard after the end of the CardView?
I saw some similar questions here, but none of them provide a solution that I need. Some answers suggest to set a paddingBotton in EditText, but that is not what I want. I don't want space, I want to show the end of the CardView too.

Note that I don't want to resize the layout, so "adjustResize" is not the solution and I'm already using "adjustPan" in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
    ...
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: is this layout in scrollview ?

Comment: Did you get any solution yet ?

Comment: Not yet. I'm using paddingBotton in EditText as a workaround for now.

Comment: But I think the problem is with the scrollView when the keyboards is open, because I can't scroll down and if I scroll up, I can't view the full layout, I can scroll just a little bit. Not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using scrollview. you can do one thing is to scroll your scrollview as your requirement

Please refer below code for example

```
ScrollView sv =(ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrl);
sv.scrollTo(0, sv.getBottom());

or 

sv.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
```

this action you can perform on soft input of Enter key.

There is also one other solution you can hide the suggestion of keyboard by giving

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

Comment: I'm using scrollView, but this solution didn't work because i can't scroll more then shown in the image above even if I hide the suggestions.

Comment: The edittext is visible, but with no padding between the text and the keyboard.

Comment: then only one option is left give some padding

Comment: you can also do one another thing is to hide one of above field when keyboard is open. it will ups your layout and also stop scrolling that time